# format - Help with printing a table

Tags: lisp, format

This question will probably end in a facepalm, but I've tried for a while and am still stuck despite reading through the hyperspec.

Basically what I want to do is something like

```
(format t "~{|~{ ~5d~}|~%~}" '((1 23 2 312) (23 456 1 7890)))
```

but instead of hard-coding the 5 it should be calculated from the list (length of longest element from any nested list + 1) to give something like

```
|    1    23     2   312|
|   23   456     1  7890|
```

Maybe I'm thinking way too complicated here and there is an easier way to do what I want, but I think I ran myself into a mental corner that I can't get out of.

Comment: There may well be a `~` control to do what you want, but I'd just do this in 2 steps: compute the widest element, then build a format-string (with format!) using that, then call format to build the table.  So it's a 3-line function instead of a 1-line function.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Assuming the required width is bound to `width`, then you can do this:</strike>

```
(format t "~{|~{ ~Vd~}|~%~}" width '((1 23 2 312) (23 456 1 7890)))
```

`5` has been replaced by `V` and `width` has been added as an argument to `FORMAT`/

**edit: original answer did not correctly account for the nested directives**

In a format control string `V` may be used in place of any constant value, indicating that the corresponding value is to be taken from the argument list instead.

You can try this:

```
(setf width 5)
(setf data '((1 23 2 312) (23 456 1 7890)))

(format t "~{|~{ ~{~Vd~}~}|~%~}"
  (mapcar #'(lambda (r) (mapcar #'(lambda (v) (list width v)) r)) data) )
```

This format string requires the desired width to precede each value.  The `(mapcar ...)` expression accomplishes this.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. The maximum width is at least easy to compute (at least if all the numbers are positive). For example, `(1+ (apply #'max (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (floor (log x 10))) '(1 10 100 1000 200000))))`.

Comment: I have conciously rejected this solution because ad hoc splicing the width into the argument list seems needlessly complicated and wasteful to me.

Comment: +1 and accepted since `V` was exactly what I was looking for (and missed repeatedly it seems). I do see Svanet's point though, so +1 there too :)

Comment: @Svante: I agree that splicing the widths into the list can be costly.  However, a call to FORMAT is fairly costly as well.  The list splicing would be less expensive (in both space and time) for small lists and more expensive for large lists.  The cross-over point would have to be determined by benchmarking with real data.  The double-format approach definitely scales better -- especially in space.  My main motive in this answer was to point out the utility of 'V' in format control strings.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you have two options:  let the `format` magic go and use other looping constructs or generate the format string itself:

```
(defun facepalm-printer (lol)
  (format t (format nil "~~{|~~{ ~~~ad~~}|~~%~~}"
                    (longest-member lol))
          lol))
```

The definition of `longest-member` is left as an exercise to the reader.