# Pretty-print values in fixed-width fields

Tags: format, lisp, common-lisp, multidimensional-array

I'd like to pretty-print in fixed-width fields a matrix made up of its column names and its values. Here's the code I wrote:

```
(defstruct
  (matrix
    (:print-function (lambda (my-matrix stream depth)
                     (declare (ignore depth))
                     (let* ((dimensions (matrix-dimensions my-matrix))
                            (column-names (matrix-column-names my-matrix))
                            (values (matrix-values my-matrix))
                            (number-of-rows (nth 0 dimensions))
                            (number-of-columns (nth 1 dimensions)))
                       (progn (loop :for i :upto number-of-columns
                                 :do (if (< i number-of-columns)
                                         (format stream (nth i column-names))
                                         (format stream "~%")))
                              (loop :for j :upto (1- number-of-rows)
                                 :do (loop :for k :upto number-of-columns
                                        :do (if (< k number-of-columns)
                                                (format stream (write-to-string (aref values j k)))
                                                (format stream "~%")))))))))
  dimensions
  column-names
  values)
```

However, if I run this code, here's what I get:

```
CL-USER> (make-matrix :dimensions '(3 2)
                  :column-names '("Michael" "Alexandra")
                  :values (make-array '(3 2) :initial-contents '((54 34) (65 78) (49 38))))
MichaelAlexandra
5434
6578
4938
```

How can I edit my :print-function (and more specifically its format part) so that both column names and values are neatly printed in fixed-width fields?

I read there exists a ~w directive in format for such purpose but didn't really grasp how it works.

Comment: You might get mileage out of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618503/format-help-with-printing-a-table), [this chapter](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html), and [this section](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm) of the Hyperspec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"~NN"` in the `format` directive:

```
(defstruct
  (matrix
    (:print-function (lambda (my-matrix stream depth)
                       (declare (ignore depth))
                       (let* ((dimensions (matrix-dimensions my-matrix))
                              (column-names (matrix-column-names my-matrix))
                              (values (matrix-values my-matrix))
                              (number-of-rows (nth 0 dimensions))
                              (number-of-columns (nth 1 dimensions)))
                         (loop :for i :upto number-of-columns
                           :do (if (< i number-of-columns)
                                   (format stream "~10s" (nth i column-names))
                                   (terpri stream)))
                         (loop :for j :upto (1- number-of-rows)
                           :do (loop :for k :upto number-of-columns
                                 :do (if (< k number-of-columns)
                                         (format stream "~10s" (aref values j k))
                                         (terpri stream))))))))
  dimensions
  column-names
  values)
```

PS. You do not need `progn` in `let`

Comment: This works very well. The only remaining issue I have not solved yet is how to print the column-names without the quotation marks. As of now, if I run (make-matrix :dimensions '(3 2) :column-names '("Michael" "Alexandra") :values (make-array '(3 2) :initial-contents '((54 34) (65 78) (49 38)))), "Michael" and "Alexandra" will get printed into quotation marks. How do I get them printed without quotation marks?

Comment: Use `~A` instead of `~S` for names.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it with CLOS, the Common Lisp Object System.

A matrix class with three initargs:

```
(defclass matrix ()
  ((dimensions   :initarg :dimensions)
   (column-names :initarg :column-names)
   (values       :initarg :values)))
```

A `print-matrix` method:

```
(defmethod print-matrix ((matrix matrix) &optional (stream *standard-output*))
  (with-slots (dimensions column-names values)
      matrix
    (destructuring-bind (number-of-rows number-of-columns)
        dimensions
      (dotimes (i number-of-columns)
        (format stream "~10a" (nth i column-names)))
      (terpri stream)
      (dotimes (j number-of-rows)
        (dotimes (k number-of-columns)
          (format stream "~10s" (aref values j k)))
        (terpri stream)))))
```

Try it:

```
? (print-matrix (make-instance 'matrix
                  :dimensions '(3 2)
                  :column-names '("Michael" "Alexandra")
                  :values (make-array '(3 2)
                            :initial-contents '((54 34) (65 78) (49 38)))))
Michael   Alexandra 
54        34        
65        78        
49        38
```

Changing the default printer for the class:

```
(defmethod print-object ((matrix matrix) stream)
  (print-matrix matrix stream))
```

Comment: Why would you use the CLOS Rainer? I know a class offers more options than a structure, so I would assume computing is more costly when dealing with classes than with structures. Why not just using structures as long as you do not classes features such as multiple inheritance etc?

Comment: @Alexandre: use always CLOS. Use only structures when you absolutely need (and don't get) *performance*.

Comment: Why do you recommend to always use the CLOS?

Comment: @Alexandre: why use two ways to define records? Choose the better one which is better integrated into the Lisp philosophy. That's CLOS. Be consistent. Knuth in 1974: *We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.*

Comment: One _huge_ advantage of `defstruct`, IMNSHO, is the presence of a *useful* default `print-object` method. (I _know_ why there is no such method for _defclass_).